# Jquery and getJson, only works when using alert()

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, getjson

I am having trouble with my jquery. It seems to be acting oddly. This is what's going on. I trying to obtain an equation from JSON file and evaluating with knockout observable objects.

What's weird about it, is that it only works when I use any alert('') message, without it, it just doesn't work.

I googled my question and the answers i get is regard ajax call. But im using jQuery function $getJSON here

Code

```
 function loadData(fileName) { 
     var data = $.getJSON( fileName + ".json");
     return(data);
 }

     var res = 0;

     var Student = function(data) {
     var self = this;
     ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { }, self);
      var res = 0;
     self.result = ko.computed(function() {
        loadData("Eqn").done(function(data1) { 
            if (data1 && data1.eqn) {
                $.each(data1.eqn, function(key, value){
                    var str = value.Equation;
                    res = eval (str);
                }); 
            }
        });
        return(res);    
     });   
  };
```

Everything is working fine if i add an alert before return().

Eqn.json

```
{
   "eqn":[
      {
         "Equation":"parseFloat(self.English()) + parseFloat(self.Japanese()) + parseFloat(self.Calculus()) + parseFloat(self.Geometry())"
      }
   ]
}
```

Data.json

```
{
   "info":[
      {
         "Name":"Noob Here",
         "Major":"Language",
         "Sex":"Male",
         "English":"15",
         "Japanese":"5",
         "Calculus":"0",
         "Geometry":"20"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Noob Here",
         "Major":"Calculus",
         "Sex":"Female",
         "English":"0.5",
         "Japanese":"40",
         "Calculus":"20",
         "Geometry":"05"
      }
   ]
}
```

Complete code is in [here](http://jsbin.com/ipeseq/10/edit)

Comment: ***It's asynchronous !!!***

Comment: let `self.result` be a simple observable, and change its value in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

so the main problem was, that the dependencies were fetched from the JSON data. following workaround proved to be the solution:

```
self.eqn = ko.observable(null); 
self.reslut = ko.computed(function(){ return self.eqn() && eval( self.eqn() ); });
loadData("Eqn").done(function(data1) { 
  if (data1 && data1.eqn) { 
    $.each(data1.eqn, function(key, value){ 
      self.eqn( value.Equation;); 
    });
  }
});
```

===========================================

you cannot return from an asynchronous function. you need to set a helper observable, whose value will change in a callback from getJSON.

right now i dont see why your computed cant be an observable.

```
// let self.result be a simple observable
self.result = ko.observable();
// now call the function to update self.result
loadData("Eqn").done(function(data1) { 
    if (data1 && data1.eqn) {
        $.each(data1.eqn, function(key, value){
            var str = value.Equation;
            res = eval (str);
            // set the value of self.result to the result of 
            // your computing function
            self.result( res );
        }); 
    }
})
```

you only need to use `ko.computed` if the variable depends on another `ko.observable`

```
var a = ko.observable("peter"),
    b = ko.computed(function(){ return "hi " + a (); });
```

in this case, whenever you update a, b will be updated. so you can see it as a short hand for the following

```
var a = ko.observable("peter"),
    b = ko.observable("hi peter");
a.subscribe(function(v){ b( "hi " + v ); });
```

Comment: I need to set it as computed.

Comment: why exaclty does it need to be a `ko.computed`. on which observable does it depend? as I see it now, there is truly no need for it to be a `computed`. just set the value to be the answer from your `computing` function, like in my example.

Comment: you only need `ko.computed` if you want the value to be dependand on another `ko.observable`. see my explanation above

Comment: Have you seen my JS-Bin? My Result depends on all the other computed elements.

Comment: sorry, still don't see it. which variable does the computed depend upon? the only variable in your computed function is `data1` and that is returned by `getJSON`

Comment: in any case, maybe this doc will help you to solve the problem: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Asynchronous-Dependent-Observables

Comment: The variables i use are mapped using knockout-mapping plugin from a json file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26859/discussion-between-lordvlad-and-sreekesh-okky)